# Multiple clones Sanger sequencing analysis

Tags: dna-sequencing

I am doing a 96-well arrayed cloning. I have done Gibson, transformations and minipreps in a 96-well format, then sent out the plate for sequencing. Normally, I sequence 3-4 clones and check if the sequencing looks good manually with Benchling cause it has nice visualization tool that highlights mismatches but also displays sequence quality. Now I have to check the sequences of 96 individual clones. Obviously I can write a simple script that would do alignments and report the alignment quality. However, I am guessing there should be already tools available that work with Sanger clonal sequences and provide nice visualization for many alignments at once. Any recommendations for specific tools I should use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't personally used it but [seqtrace](https://bio.tools/seqtrace) seems to be targeted for this purpose. It seems to be able to do alignments and facilitates multiple trace file analysis.

I worry a little bit about not visually inspecting trace files for sequencing of clones, but I may be a relative dinosaur (about sanger at least).

Here is the abstract:

> Modern applications of Sanger DNA sequencing often require converting a large number of chromatogram trace files into high-quality DNA sequences for downstream analyses. Relatively few nonproprietary software tools are available to assist with this process. SeqTrace is a new, free, and open-source software application that is designed to automate the entire workflow by **facilitating easy batch processing of large numbers of trace files**. SeqTrace can identify, align, and compute consensus sequences from matching forward and reverse traces, filter low-quality base calls, and end-trim finished sequences. The software features a **graphical interface that includes a full-featured chromatogram viewer** and sequence editor. SeqTrace runs on most popular operating systems and is freely available, along with supporting documentation, at http://seqtrace. googlecode.com/.© 2012 ABRF.